# sklearn minmaxscaler ported to a different notebook

Tags: import, scikit-learn, scaling, preprocessor

How would I go about downloading the min_max_scaler attributes so that I could apply the same transform to data within a different notebook?

For full disclosure I've trained a NN within one notebook, and am running it in a different locations. It is simple for me to load the trained weights of the NN in the second location, but I need to scale the data before inputting it into the model. To be accurate I believe it has to use the original scale attributes.

Comment: Reading the documentation a little more, would I just subtract the new data by min_max_scaler.min_ and then divide it by min_max_scaler.scale_?

Comment: Can't you just use `pickle` to save the object? Without the code this question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html), you can recreate what min max scaler does using

```
X_std = (X - X.min(axis=0)) / (X.max(axis=0) - X.min(axis=0))
X_scaled = X_std * (max - min) + min
```

where X is your original dataset. (Although as long as your feature range is the default of (0,1), the second line above is not needed - you will come out with `X_scaled = X_std`)

If you want to do this same computation using your already trained MaxMinScaler instead of your original dataset, consider the following example (again assuming feature range is left at the default (0,1))

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Test data set
X = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(20,4)))

# Test scaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
sklearn_result = scaler.fit_transform(X)

# Compute, and verify results match up to machine precision
manual_result = (X - scaler.data_min_)/(scaler.data_max_ - scaler.data_min_)
(sklearn_result - test).max().max() . # Is around 10e-16
```